# Export all ElasticSearch data to JSON file

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, connection, export-to-text

I need t export all data in the ElasticSearch and reindex all those data.

The export Java code as follows.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("news")
                .setTypes("news_data")
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                .setSize(1000)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000))
                .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
                .execute().actionGet();
        String scrollid = response.getScrollId();
        try {
            //把导出的结果以JSON的格式写到文件里
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("es", true));

            while (true) {
                SearchResponse response2 = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollid)
                        .setScroll(new TimeValue(1000000))
                        .execute().actionGet();
                SearchHits searchHit = response2.getHits();
                //再次查询不到数据时跳出循环
                if (searchHit.getHits().length == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("查询数量 ：" + searchHit.getHits().length);
                for (int i = 0; i < searchHit.getHits().length; i++) {
                    String json = searchHit.getHits()[i].getSourceAsString();
                    out.write(json);
                    out.write("\r\n");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("查询结束");
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The numbers of documents is about 140W. Use this java code 60W documents can be exported and throw an exception.

```
远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接
```

Comment: First, you need to update your scrollid inside your while loop.

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan

`The initial search request and each subsequent scroll request returns a new _scroll_id — only the most recent _scroll_id should be used.`

Second.. not sure how much memory your application will consume with keeping the FileWriter open for all your messages. Perhaps you're better off writing several files and closing inbetween scroll requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the scrollid from the previous response for your next request.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan for more details

Perhaps you can try something like this instead?

```
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("news")
            .setTypes("news_data")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
            .setSize(1000)
            .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000))
            .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
            .execute().actionGet();
    int sequence = 0;
    do
    {
        response = client.prepareSearchScroll(response.getScrollId())
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000))
                .execute().actionGet();
        if (response.getHits().getHits().length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("es-" + (++sequence) , true));
                for (final SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits())
                {
                    out.write(hit.getSourceAsString());
                    out.write("\r\n");
                }
                out.close();
            }
            catch (final IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    while (response.getHits().hits().length > 0);
```